# Initialise AngularJS after async postback

Tags: angularjs, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've got AngularJS code working as part of the page where we use AJAX Control Toolkit.

After clicking a button which is inside update panel (async postback) AngularJS is not re-initialized.

How can I re initialize it after async postback?

Example which works for jQuery:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () {
   //re initialize js jQuery code
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS with ASP.NET Updatepanel partial update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832540/angularjs-with-asp-net-updatepanel-partial-update)

Answer (score 0):

If you make model changes in a callback outside of Angular (which is what it sounds like you want to do), you can let Angular become aware of the changes by calling `$rootScope.$apply()`. This will start the digest loop which will update all views, trigger watches etc.